# Spring REST (Jersey) with ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jackson

I have a pair of related objects that I want to publish via Spring Jersey REST.

Two objects (as examples):

**Library**

```
public class Library {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="library")
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

**Book**

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Library library;
}
```

http://localhost/book/72 shows

```
{"id": 72, "title": "my book"}
```

http://localhost/library/36 shows

```
{"id": 36, "name": "our library"}
```

Now my end-user wants to move books between libraries. So, for me it seems useful to first show the relationship from book to library like this:

http://localhost/book/72 shows

```
{"id": 72, "title": "my book", "libraryId": 36}
```

And then users are able to PUT on http://localhost/book/72

```
{"id": 72, "title": "my book", "libraryId": 12}
```

The user moved the book between library 36 and 12.

Is that a normal situation in Spring REST + Jersey?
How to accomplish this?

Normally the **@ManyToOne** gets ignored **(@JsonIgnore)** to prevent from having:

> {"id": 72, "title": "my book", "library": {"id": 36, "name": "our
>   library"}}

My Question is:

**Question 1:** how to get this 'libraryId' attribute there in the simplest form?

**Question 2:** how to translate this back when PUT/POST'ing?

Comment: If found this link: http://www.insaneprogramming.be/blog/2013/07/13/circular-dependencies-with-jackson/. Might get helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a dummy property;

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Library library;

public Long getLibraryId() {
     library.getId();
}

public void setLibraryId(Long id) {
     library.setId(id);
}
```

If you add Jackson to you pom, JSON should automatically produced, if you annotate the RestController wth

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1-1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a spring example, not Jersey but you get the idea, Jackson just has to be in the classpath.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  @ResponseBody  Long update(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return ...
    }
```